# How to get unity desktop on ubuntu 16.04 server?

Tags: unity, server, kde

I have a problem with one of my boxes such that the GUI login does not work. I ssh'd to it and backed it up to my network and want to upgrade it to 16.04 from 14.04 with a fresh 16.04 install.  Since I have it set up with 2 ssd in raid 0 (it boots from a small raid1 partition). I want to keep the same partition setup, so I need to use the server dist.  I have another  box with the same setup, so I set up a server usb stick and went through the normal server install.  Somehow I ended up with the KDE desktop, which I do not like.  I did the sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^ and ubuntu now appears as a choice in a dropdown on login, but it locks up when you try to log in with that option. Otherwise things are working fine.  I was wondering if this still works for 16.04.  I can't remember if I did something special to get the KDE desktop, but I want to get this sorted before I upgrade my other machine. Sorry for so many words.
Thanks

Comment: Did you install lightdm?  It should be installed, and then run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to select lightdm as your display manager to run Unity.

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a try tonight. If I reload from scratch, or when I do my other machine, can I just install lightdm by itself?

Comment: If you're installing the vanilla Ubuntu image, it defaults to using lightdm with the Unity desktop (ubuntu-desktop).